# How do I make .remove() work consistently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am working on some Python homework and somehow the .remove() function does not work properly and I can't explain why.

Input:

```
['', '', 'Age,Gender,Weight (kg),Height (cm)', '28,Female,58,168', '33,Male,,188', '', '', '', '', '21, Male, 95, 198']
```

My code:

```
    for l in first:
        if str(l) == "":
            first.remove(l)
    print(first)
```

Output:

```
['Age,Gender,Weight (kg),Height (cm)', '28,Female,58,168', '33,Male,,188', '', '', '', '21, Male, 95, 198']
```

As you can see, the empty strings in the front get removed as intended but the ones later on don't. How do I properly clean the list by using "basic" Python syntax?

Comment: I think the `str(l)` is not necessary, but I don't see how that would affect anything.

Comment: never alter list while iterating over it.

Comment: Your code will work if you change the `for` line to `for l in list(first):` because this iterates over a copy of `first` then the subsequent lines can remove items from `first` without modifying the thing being iterated over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is by doing a list comprehension:

```py
li = ['', '', 'Age,Gender,Weight (kg),Height (cm)', '28,Female,58,168', '33,Male,,188', '', '', '', '', '21, Male, 95, 198']
li = [s for s in li if s != ""]
print(li)  # ['Age,Gender,Weight (kg),Height (cm)', '28,Female,58,168', '33,Male,,188', '21, Male, 95, 198']
```

As @ShadowRanger noted, you can also more simply write it this way:

```py
li = [s for s in li if s]
```

since `""` evaluates to `False`.

Comment: Did you copy @Wasif Hasan?

Comment: `if s` will do the trick without `!= ''`; the empty string is falsy, so non-empty strings will be kept. And this technically doesn't modify the original `list` (often not a problem, but worth nothing).

Comment: @zixuan: This is the standard answer for this *many* times duplicated question. People will naturally produce the same answer, because it's the simple, obvious answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
myList = ['', '', 'Age,Gender,Weight (kg),Height (cm)', '28,Female,58,168', '33,Male,,188', '', '', '', '', '21, Male, 95, 198']
myList = [x for x in myList if x != '']
```

You can use `if x` shorthand too as proposed by @shadowRanger:

```
myList = [x for x in myList if x]
```

Comment: `if x` will do the trick without `!= ''`; the empty string is falsy, so non-empty strings will be kept. And this technically doesn't modify the original `list` (often not a problem, but worth nothing).